# ajax request response false data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

i have a page and i want to refresh a div every minute without to refresh whole page.Div get data from a php file who calculate the bigger price in an another xml file.I read that the best way to do it is ajax request.

my ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var name = $("#product").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "maxPrice.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {'product_name' : name}, 
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus);
     },
    success:function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

the php file:

```
<?php
$product_name = $_GET['product_name'];

    $loop = 0;
    $auction_price_db = 0;
    $id_product = id_from_product_name($product_name);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('C:/wamp/www/store/connections/auctions.xml');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $xml_offers = simplexml_load_file('C:/wamp/www/store/connections/offers.xml');
    $xml_auctions = simplexml_load_file('C:/wamp/www/store/connections/auctions.xml');

    foreach ($xml_auctions->auction as $auction){
         if ($auction->auction_id == $id_product) {
             $auction_price_db = (string)$auction->start_price;
             $item = $loop;
             break;
         }
         $loop++;
    }

      foreach ($xml_offers->offer as $offer){
         if ($offer->id_product == $id_product) {
             $user_offer = (string)$offer->price;
             if ($user_offer > $auction_price_db) {
                 $parent = $doc->getElementsByTagName('auction')->item($item);
                 $query = $xpath->query('start_price',$parent);
                 $query->item(0)->nodeValue = $user_offer;
                 $doc->save('C:/wamp/www/store/connections/auctions.xml');
                 $xml_products = simplexml_load_file('C:/wamp/www/store/connections/products.xml');
                 foreach ($xml_products->product as $product){
                       if ($id_product == $product->product_id) {
                           $product->price = $user_offer;
                           $xml_products->asXML('connections/products.xml');
                       }
                 }
                $response =  "{\"user_offer\":\"".$user_offer."\"}";
             }
         }
    }
echo <<<HERE_DOC
$response
HERE_DOC;

?>
```

In success of ajax i have an alert to see if the data from ajax is right.But it response with this..

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Call to undefined function id_from_product_name() in C:\wamp\www\store\maxPrice.php on line <i>6</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0004</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>692568</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\store\maxPrice.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\maxPrice.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Why i get this response?If i try to delete all code from maxPrice and echo only the $product_name that i pass it in the ajax request i get the right data.

Comment: `undefined function id_from_product_name() in C:\wamp\www\store\maxPrice.php on line 6` seems to be the issue so `$id_product = id_from_product_name($product_name);` is bombing out

Comment: There is an error and you are sending back the call stack. The error is right there in it "Fatal error: Call to undefined function id_from_product_name() in C:\wamp\www\store\maxPrice.php on line.."

Comment: why?I know that this function works fine.id_from_product_name is an another php file.I must put it in the same?

Comment: You must include the script where the function is defined. When you make an ajax call, that is a new request, so all the stuff you need to build your page / response needs to be done again. There is nothing *left* (no status, variables, etc.) of the original page load.

Comment: Thanks.I will try your suggestion to see the results.Thanks again

Comment: If you don't like reading the output of the Network tab then a good way to debug AJAX issues is to actually visit the `maxPrice.php` url in your browser because in essence AJAX is doing just that. If you do not know what the Network tab is then please use Google Chrome and press F12

Answer (score 0):

That's an Xdebug-formatted error from the server. If you look closely on line 3, you'll see this error message from the server:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function id_from_product_name() in C:\wamp\www\store\maxPrice.php on line 6
```